# Read-Only File with Pear-Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, pear

I'm generating Excel file with ..Pear-Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.3

My file is generated without any errors but, it is in < Read-Only > Mode,

I researched but couldn't find the result except, 
permission on my local folders where excel output is stored,
I tried all CHMOD things, but still the file is being generated in Read-Only Mode.
I want to disable this Read-Only Mode.

sample Code is....

```
    <?php

    require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
    $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer('/tmp/yXcel.ods');

    //$workbook->setTempDir('/tmp/');
    $format_bold =& $workbook->addFormat();
    $format_bold->setBold();

    $format_title =& $workbook->addFormat();
    $format_wrap =& $workbook->addFormat();
    $format_title->setBold();
    $format_title->setColor('yellow');
    $format_title->setPattern(10);
    $format_title->setFgColor('blue');
    // let's merge
    $format_title->setAlign('merge');
    $format_wrap->setTextWrap(2);

    $format_top =& $workbook->addFormat();
    $format_top->setAlign('top');
    $format_top->setTextWrap(1);

    // center the text horizontally
    $format_center =& $workbook->addFormat();
    $format_center->setAlign('center');

    // put text at the top and center it horizontally
    $format_top_center =& $workbook->addFormat();
    $format_top_center->setAlign('top');
    $format_top_center->setAlign('center');



    $worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet();
    $worksheet->write(0, 0, "Title with Merged Cells", $format_title);
    // Couple of empty cells to make it look better
    $worksheet->write(0, 1, "", $format_title);
    $worksheet->write(0, 2, "", $format_title);
    $worksheet->write(0, 3, "", $format_title);
    $worksheet->write(1, 0, "Quarter", $format_bold);
    $worksheet->write(1, 1, "Profit", $format_bold);
    $worksheet->write(2, 0, "Q1asddddddddddddddddddddddddd",$format_wrap);
    $worksheet->write(2, 1, 2205,$format_top_center);
    $worksheet->write(3, 0, "Q2",$format_wrap);
    $worksheet->write(3, 1, 3305,$format_top);

    //$workbook->send('test1.xls');
    $workbook->close(); 
    ?>
```

I solved it by

```
 chmod('/tmp/yXcel.ods',0777)
```

Still, Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

> < Read-Only > Mode

Excel spreadsheets does not have "read only" mode. The main of Excel or LibreOffice reporting sheet as read-only are usually related to spread sheet file permissions (or ownership of that file) which may simply block writes but not reads. Once you download/copy the file to location owned by you should be able to edit it as well. If still not, ensure if file permission is not preventing it too.

Comment: I already mentioned, that I tried all CHMOD things, but couldn't be succeeded.  However, I solved it by PHP's chmod() function. Thank you !

Comment: not sure what `CHMOD things` really means, but if chmod helped, then it seems your rights were insufficient for write. Still, `chmod 777` is not a fix  but a bad workaround. and it is bad, because giving `7` to `world` is not good practice.